# How to fetch the Limited records(pagination) from the database using GraphQL

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql

I am recently started working with GraphQL. I am able to fetch all the records from the database, but I want to get only limited records (like 10 at a time).
Any one please guide me to achieve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd pass the number of items to be returned as a parameter, and then use `limit` on MongoDB.

Type definition:

```
fields: () => {
  posts: {
    resolve: (root, params) => Post.find().limit(params.first)
  }
}
```

Example query:

```
{
  posts(first: 10) {
    id
    text
    date
  }
}
```